# WebStorm encoding problems in terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, zsh, webstorm

I'm having encoding problems, but only in the terminal of WebStorm. WebStorm's GUI and text editors are all set to UTF-8:

[image]
[image]

But when I compare terminal output between OSX and WebStorm's terminal window:

From WebStorm's terminal:

```
$ echo $0

/bin/zsh

$ locale

LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

From OSX terminal:

```
$ echo $0

-zsh

$ locale

LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

How do I correctly set the encoding for Webstorm's terminal pane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue, [IDEA-121713](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-121713). Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-121713#comment=27-709456 for possible workaround. Another way to go - try opening WebStorm from system terminal (`open -a /Applications/WebStorm.app/`)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out it's a known issue. I was hesitant to do the system-wide fix: `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8  
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`